# How can I bring up a console alongside my LibGDX desktop application?

Tags: java, testing, libgdx

I would like to see some of the System.out and accept some inputs from it for testing my application on other computers which do not have Eclipse on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you run the jar by double-clicking then the console output won't be shown.

However, you can launch the command line application (Terminal/CMD depending on your OS) then use the `cd` command to navigate to the directory of the jar file. Then type:

```
java -jar [app_name.jar]
```

This will run the application and show output within the console.

Comment: This is definitely what I want, Now if you can programmatically make this occur when opening the jar then you get an instant check mark.